# How to change the default font from Myriad pro to some other font in case of missing font?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, cc-2017

How do I change the default font in photoshop.

Comment: Are you referring to the Type Tool (Character palette) or are you wanting to change the Photoshop software menu fonts?

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop 'default' font is usually determined by the **font you last used**. So if you last used Myriad Pro and leave Photoshop, it will be the 'default' font when you open ps again.

That's how it works with CC anyhow.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I've never used Myriad Pro in my life yet Photoshop INSISTS on constantly choosing it every type I select the type tool. It's infuriating.

Answer (score 1):

Type -> Panels -> Character Styles Panel -> double click on None in the Character Style Options -> change Font Family to your desired font -> OK

I had the same problem whenever I pasted a symbol which the font didn't support, so it changed back to Myriad Pro. But that font doesn't even display symbols. Segoe UI Symbol does it though.